# I am an instrument, but you do not play me

Tags: riddle

I'm learning to make more complex riddles, but until then I enjoy these.

(Title too)

*I hold something of which many desire more.*

*I can use water, the stars and even sand.*

*I have been made and remade more times than most know.*

*What am I?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are

> An instrument for telling time

```
(Title) I am an instrument, but you do not play me
```

> An instrument for telling time

```
I hold something of which many desire more.
```

> Most people wish they had more time.  An hourglass, in particular, metaphorically holds time ("the sands of time")

```
I can use water, the stars and even sand.
```

> There are water clocks, [star clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_clock), and of course hourglasses.

```
I have been made and remade more times than most know.
```

> Lots of different types of clocks have been made and improved upon over history.  (And most clocks have to be rewound or reset frequently.)

Comment: Yup, thought of clock initially but generally that works haha. Nice... This one wasn't as hard I guess... Or you're just really good at these